# jquery background-position

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

So I've implemented parallax scrolling and it all works good, but I ran into a small error and would like certain panels to have their background-images affected by the parallax.

In short, for some odd reason, I can't modify the background-position values at all. There aren't any changes that show in the inspector in my browser, or any errors. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            //MANAGING PARALLAX SCROLLING

            var currentScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
            $("#hero-bg").css({'top' : 'calc(' + currentScrollPosition/30 + 'rem ' + ' - 10rem)'});
            //^^^WORKS FINE

            $("#panel2").css({'background-position' : '0rem ' + -currentScrollPosition/50 + 'rem'});
            //^^^DOESN'T WORK
            console.log(-currentScrollPosition/50 + 'rem');
        });
```

Here is an attached snippet demonstrating what I'm attempting to do.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
 //MANAGING PARALLAX SCROLLING
 var currentScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
 $("#panel2").css({backgroundPosition : '0rem ' + -currentScrollPosition/50 + 'rem'});
 console.log(-currentScrollPosition/50 + 'rem');
});
```

```css
#body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50rem;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 1;
}

#panel2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20rem;
  top: 10rem;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="panel2" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `console.log( -currentScrollPosition/50 )` and see what you have there

Comment: yes, now that I made this change it works, sortof. Inspector says its changing and shows values, but I see no result...

Comment: Check that you have unique ID on that page (sometimes it's a reason). Another way is to add parentheses between concatenated values to change operators precedence.

Comment: I run a one-page website for ease of use and speed, each page has a #panel2 in it, but only 1 page is visible at a time.

Comment: no matter how many pages (sections) are visible, it may not work if there are just few the same IDs exists on loaded html-page.

Comment: I came up with a solution I will try out, I only manipulate the '#panel2' that is a child of the '.current' page.

Comment: changing the id to a class fixed it.... (facepalm for such a simple fix)

Comment: @BudBroesky please post an answer here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the id to a class ("panel2" to ".panel2") fixed it... I was WAY overthinking it.